# jQuery validation plugin refreshes IE8

Tags: jquery, validation, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-dialog

Validating a form with the jQuery validation plugin (v1.10.0) coupled with a jQueryUI dialog (v1.9.0, and not 1.9.1 as CDN'ed) and of course jQuery (v1.8.2) refreshes the page on both IE7 and IE8 and does not generate any error, while it works like a charm with any other tested browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE9).

Here's the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.0/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var deleteTestAndReload;
var deleteTestWithMotive;
var display;
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $deleteTestDialog = $('<div id="delete-test-dialog"></div>').dialog({
        autoOpen:   false,
        title:      'Delete test',
        height:     340,
        width:      590,
        modal:      true,
        position:   ['center', 50]
    });

    deleteTestAndReload = function() {
        alert("Aouch, Charlie!");
        $deleteTestDialog.dialog('close');
    }

    deleteTestWithMotive = function() {
        html = '    <form id="delete-test-dialog-form" name="delete-test-dialog-form" onsubmit="deleteTestAndReload(); return false;" method="post">\n';
        html += '   Why?<br />\n';
        html += '   <input type="radio" id="motive-1" name="motive" value="1" checked="checked" />Charlie bit me<br />\n';
        html += '   <div style="text-align:right;">\n';
        html += '   <button id="validate_test_deletion" name="validate_test_deletion" type="submit" value="test_deletion">Delete</button>\n';
        html += '   </div>';
        html += '   </form>\n';

        $("#delete-test-dialog").html(html);

        $("#delete-test-dialog-form").validate({
            rules: {
                motive: { required: true }
            }
        });

        $("#validate_test_deletion", "#delete-test-dialog-form").button();
    }

    display = function() {
        alert('display');
        html = '<button type="button" name="delete_test" value="delete_test" class="my-buttonset-button" onclick="deleteTestWithMotive();">Delete</button>\n';
        $("#main-content").html(html);

        $("button[name='delete_test']").button().click(function() {
            $deleteTestDialog.dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    }

    display();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

On loading, a first javascript alert is called ('display').
When clicking on the Delete button, a Dialog opens with a form within, and when that form is validated (radio button checked and button Delete clicked), a second function is called (deleteTestAndReload) which alerts a message (it fires an ajax call in the full version) and closes the dialog instance.

On IE7/IE8, the page refreshes and the first alert ('display') is displayed (the reload is the bug, as it shouldn't).

However, if I remove the following validation code, it works with no reload.

```
$("#delete-test-dialog-form").validate({
    rules: {
        motive: { required: true }
    }
});
```

So I'm assuming something goes wrong when validating the form.

Comment: `.validate()` is meant to _initialize_ the form for validation.  It should be called upon DOM ready.  Instead, you are calling it within the `deleteTestWithMotive` function.  In other words, the form is not even ready for validation until it's initialized.  Simply move `.validate()` outside the `deleteTestWithMotive` and into the `document.ready` function.

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

You have a couple of options that you can change to make this work cross-browser. I went ahead and recreated your above scenario in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cWea7/ so that I could make some tweaks and show them below.

#### Option 1

Use the `submitHandler` property when setting up the `validate` plugin

```
$("#delete-test-dialog-form").validate({
    submitHandler: deleteTestAndReload,
    rules: {
        motive: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

Notes: I removed the `onsubmit` attribute from the `form` tag since that will be handled by the `submitHandler` as shown in the above snippet.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cWea7/9/

#### Option 2

In the `submit` event handler manually check the validity of the form using the plugin's `valid` method.

```
deleteTestAndReload = function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ( $("#delete-test-dialog-form").valid() ) {
        alert("Aouch, Charlie!");
        $deleteTestDialog.dialog('close');
    }
};
```

Notes: I removed the `onsubmit` attribute from the `form` tag and instead used jQuery to wire up the `submit` event.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cWea7/8/

Comment: Wow! It works like a charm, thanks a lot! Does the solution one means I was sending the form twice, one time with the form submit, and the second with the validate plugin? Or does it have something to do with the event bubbling in Internet Explorer?